Present perfect for hypothetical situation

I am sorry but I opened a PayPal  dispute as you have not answered to my emails .
If you had already sent them , I would happily make another PayPal payment once I have received the proof of the shipment of the records because I want these records.

Is present perfect valid here? could I use  received past simple ?

Of course not. The choice is between present perfect and the simple present. The latter is just like French.

Your sentence vacillates between something that did not happen in the past as  explanation for some action you have already taken, and what you are still willing to do now.  You can't do both at the same time when the opening condition is:

If you had already sent them...

If you had already sent them, I would have made another payment.
Not "I will happily make".
Both of the following would be grammatical:

If you have already sent them, I will happily make another payment once I have received proof.
If you have already sent them, I will happily make another payment when I  receive proof.


would  have made means that it would have been done  but it is not what I mean . If I had the proof of shipment I would now (not before) make another payment

Your sentence makes no clear sense because you're mixing tenses improperly.   You need to say "If you have already sent them, I will make payment as soon as I have received proof."  Your sentence starts "If you had already sent them..."  The present perfect is needed there, not the past perfect as you had it.

Let's consider the sentence:

I would happily make another PayPal payment once I have received the proof of the shipment of the records.
Is present perfect valid here? could I use received past simple ?

Yes, present perfect is valid here but it indicates the future. You can't use Past Simple but the sentence can be rewritten with the conditional clause in the Simple Present and the Main clause in Simple Future (without changing the meaning).
It becomes a first conditional sentence.
When I receive the proof of the shipment of the records, I will happily make another PayPal payment .
In the original sentence "would" doesn't indicate a hypothetical sentence but a future intention .

Ref. preply.com.
"would" is used in the future subjunctive tense. In this situation, would can be used to describe a possible or unlikely action or scenario in the future.
For example, "I would go to the store tomorrow, if I didn't have school.".
https://preply.com/en/blog/how-to-use-will-and-would-in-english/#:~:text=Can%20we%20use%20would%20to,didn't%20have%20school.%22

